# How to leave a datepicker unfilled (with its value null)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, frontend

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC 5 website. I have the Employee model which looks something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
public EmployeeID {get;set;}
//... other properties such as FirstName, Salary which are not important right now

public DateTime? EndingDate {get; set;} //this is important
}
```

The corresponding part of the view is like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndingDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="endingDate" type="date" class="form-control datepicker" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndingDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see the EndingDate is nullable because I do not necessarily fill the EndingDate field. If I want to create an employee without filling the EndingDate I get a validation error, which makes sense because on the datepicker the value is exactly the following dd.mm.yyy. This happens on Google Chrome. On Mozilla it is null by default but is behaving like a textbox not like a datepicker. I am using bootstrapper css classes, I didn't wrote a single line of front-end development code; if you accept the language. I tried to add to model the DisplayFormat attribute but no success so far.

Any ideas? Or it is a matter of browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point a don't know any method. You can try a text box where you will fill the data and validate it in a dynamic way (using Angular by chance). Think about filing a data from a dumb phone. You enter the digits and it feels the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat= " ";
```

Comment: It's a MVC application. o you mean to put this on razor?